# passing variables from jquery ui autocomplete option success: to select:

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

In the following autocomplete script, how do I pass the results (value/label/description) to the `select:` option?

```
$( ".find_group_ac" ).autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "welcome/search/",
            data: { term: $(".find_group_ac").val()},
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data) { 
                response($.map(data, function(obj) {
                    return {
                        label: obj.name,
                        value: obj.name,
                        description: obj.description 
                    };
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    select: function (ui, item) {
        alert (item.value);
    } 

})
```

Answer (score 2):

The `select` handler is passed `event` and `ui`. `ui.item` refers to the selected item. With that in mind all you should need is:

```
select: function (event, ui) {
    alert (ui.item.label);
    alert (ui.item.value);
    alert (ui.item.description);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, worked.  I swear thats what I had first! Oh well, thanks again!